# Discord.py: How do you make buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was wondering how you can get buttons like this

[image]

Comment: you can use buttons, and components from [discord-py-slash-command](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/)

Comment: You might wanna refer to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNUuYEWGOxA

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you create an send them:

```
menu_buttons = await ctx.send(
    "Nickmenu",
    components=[
        [
            Button(
                label="Purge!", custom_id="purge", style=ButtonStyle.red, emoji=""
            ),
            Button(
                label="Raid!", custom_id="raid", style=ButtonStyle.green, emoji=""
            ),
            Button(
                label="Check!",
                custom_id="check",
                style=ButtonStyle.green,
                emoji="✅",
            ),
        ]
    ],
)
```

I used the discord components library for this.